# How to show subcategories even if parent category is disabled?

Tags: category, category-tree

How can I show the subcategories in the frontend even if the parent category is disabled?

Suppose I have categories like following

```
Electronics
           Cell phones
                      Accessories
                      Digital Camera
           Cameras
```

I Cellphone category is disabled, is it possible to still show the sub categories Accessories and Digital Camera, under Electronics category?

Comment: show them where? How?

Comment: @Marius, in the example given above if Cellphone category is disabled,I want to display the accessories and the Digital camera under Electronics.

Answer (score 1):

In short? No.
But you could override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` class, method `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` to not check for `isActive`.

You would have to commit out line `241`-`243` and probably remove the link to the category to prevent people from clicking on an inactive and non existing category.
So on line `308` it should be something like this

```
if (category->isActive()):
   $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
   $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
   $html[] = '</a>';
else:
   $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
endif;
```